# Discord Python - bot.wait_for_message in a Private Channel (DM)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Do anyone know how to use the `bot.wait_for_message` in a private channel (DM) ?

Comment: Private channels aren't treated any differently by `wait_for_message`.  What exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to accept direct private messages (not group private messages) from a specific user, you can write a check that checks `message.channel.type`

```
def check(message):
    return message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private

await bot.wait_for_message(timeout = 30, author = ctx.message.author, check=check, content="SSM")
```

If you received the command from a private channel, you can wait for that channel normally

```
await bot.wait_for_message(timeout = 30, author = ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel, content="SSM"
```

Comment: Typo.  It should be `==`